# Polynomial curve fit over datapoints in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting, polynomials

I have created a scatter plot using the `data` below with 'Age' as the x-axis and 'Rating' as the y-axis (both numerical values):

```
data = {
    'Player': ['J. Kimmich', 'Rodri', 'J. Kimmich', 'J. Kimmich', 'Thiago Alcântara', 'Sergio Busquets', 'L. Goretzka', 'Casemiro', 'Casemiro', 'Sergio Busquets'],
    'Age': [27, 25, 26, 28, 27, 31, 26, 28, 29, 30],
    'Rating': [86, 85, 85, 84, 84, 84, 83, 83, 82, 82]
}

def comparison_plot(position, x_axis, y_axis, title):

    # Opening figure & axis
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=200)
    
    # Increase the size of data points
    marker_size = 150  # You can adjust this value as needed
    
    # Plot the other data points first
    ax.scatter(x=position[x_axis], y=position[y_axis], c='#040cdb', s=marker_size)

    # Setting plot dimensions
    fig.set_size_inches(16, 9)

comparison_plot(data, x_axis = 'Age', y_axis = 'Rating', title = 'Age vs Rating')
```

I want to add a curve to the plot that looks like this black curve I drew over the original plot (i.e. the curve depicts a smooth journey over the 'peak' ratings at each age)

[image]

I have tried multiple different methods of achieving this curve (2-degree polynomial) but I can't seem to achieve the shape I want.

Comment: Do you have a full dataset? I can't reproduce your plot.

Comment: Do you want something deterministic and reproducible for the given dataset (i.e., the fit is based on some given metric such as minimising the mean square error and the curve is quadratic or polynomial to a given order) or do you just want a curve that roughly "looks right" based on your subjective expectations?